# Does using slots rather inline declarations make a component more flexible?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to make a grid component that is not too opinionated.  I have 2 different types of components that have different cover images, `DVD` and `Cassette`.
I am assuming the best way to do this is by not using `v-if`s like I am below:

**Parent.vue**

```html
<MyUniversalComponent
   :items="items"
>
</MyUniversalComponent>
```

**MyUniversalComponent.vue**

```js
import DVD from '@/components/DVD.vue';
import Cassette from '@/components/Cassette.vue';
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="grid">
       <div v-for="item in items">
           <div v-if="item.type === 'dvd'">
               <DVD :data="item" />
           </div>
           <div v-else-if="item.type === 'cassette'">
               <Cassette :data="item" />
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Is there a more flexible way to do this using slots?  I sort of want it to be a "shell" grid that can be used in different ways so I assume I'd want to take out the logic of having these components living in here. Can I translate this to use slots?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the [built-in `<component>`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component) would be more appropriate than slots. It takes an `is` prop that sets the component type, and any bindings are passed through the resolved component:

```html
<script>
import DVD from '@/components/DVD.vue';
import Cassette from '@/components/Cassette.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    DVD,
    Cassette,
  }
}
</script>

<template>
    <div class="grid">
       <div v-for="item in items">
           <component :is="item.type" :data="item" />
       </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-dynamic-component?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyUniversalComponent.vue)